# select other columns and group by SQL

Tags: sql, sum, duplicates

I have the ff. table:

[image]

as you can see i have duplicate rows for column inseciid. This data is correct btw, they differ on other columns, it just not shown in the screenshot.

I want to be able to select all columns but for those rows with the same inseciID, i want the sum(insebrbillresidentamt). so the output will be 24.00 for inseciid=4037. How do i do that using group by?

I tried doing it like this

```
select 
    sum(A.insebrBillResidentAmt) as insebrBillResidentAmt
from InspectionsBillResidentServiceAction A
group by A.inseciid
```

when i add other columns in the select statement, it requires me to add the columns in the group by clause. but in doing that, the rows get duplicated again. can you shed some light on how do i use group by in cases like this? thanks in advance

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1):

Just use max on all other columns:

```
select max(insebrid) as insebrid,
       max(inceciid) as inceciid,
       sum(insebrBillResidentAmt) as insebrBillResidentAmt,
       max(said) as said,
       max(wgid) as wgid,
       max(setID) as setID
from InspectionsBillResidentServiceAction
group by inseciid
```

Comment: Is there a problem with my answer?